# Sum specific column of values in a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum

I have this array and I want to sum up all `Hits` which figures at the `$day[$key][2]`

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01/07/13
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 3060
            [4] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 02/07/13
            [1] => 270
            [2] => 757
            [3] => 13812810
            [4] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 03/07/13
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 123
            [3] => 3894971
            [4] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 04/07/13
            [1] => 290
            [2] => 478
            [3] => 5119617
            [4] => 1
        )
```

and so on. I've tried this and it doesn't seem to work!

```
foreach ($day as $key => $value){
    $day[$key][2] += $day[$key][2];
  }
```

Any errors in my code?

Comment: What's the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

Do it with:

```
$result = array_reduce($array, function(&$cur, $x)
{
   return $cur+=$x[2];
}, 0);
```

You code also has correct logic, but you shouldn't try to modify existing array values. Just sum up into some result variable.

Comment: `array_reduce($array, function($cur, $x) { return $cur + $x[2]; }, 0)` will do just fine.

Comment: Agreed. Since it's your version, I'll leave mine (for educational purposes - so reader of this post could compare more correct version with mine)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?

```
$hits=0;
foreach($arr as $k=>$arr)
{
    $hits+=$arr[2];
}
echo $hits; //"prints" 1362
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/118677)

Comment: This will cause double loop (one in `foreach`, second in `array_sum`)- simple `foreach` would be better, I think.

Comment: @AlmaDo, Modified it.